# How to make tooltip appear instantly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, tooltip

I notice that if you use `hover`, the hidden aparts will appear instantly. But if you use a tooltip via the `title` attribute there will be a delay?

How can I remove the delay?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way. The title attribute is implemented in a browser dependent fashion. For example I remember differences between IE and FF when using \r\n inside it.

Mozilla's docs explain the limits and functionality well.

If you want customization you may take a look at third party plugins such as qTip2 which mimic it using divs and stuff and provide you full control.

You could use jqueryUI as suggested. An example of controlling the duration on the show property:

```
$( ".selector" ).tooltip({ show: { effect: "blind", duration: 0 } });
```